# Send an email notification when multiple sql jobs succeed

Tags: sql-server

So I have multiple sql jobs running on my sql server. Now I want to send an email notification to my team daily after a few muliple  selected sql jobs have succeded. How can i achieve this?
Also how can I send an email to myself whenever a job fails. But I am not the admin.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Create a group email adding all your team members

Then create a new operator (if you aren't able to do this get this done via privileged user)

[image: operator] and set your group email
[image]

After right click on SQL job and go to properties then to notifications
[image]

Ref https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4b43b4/send-an-email-notification-when-sql-job-is-failed/

Comment: Thankyou for your answer but how can I send an email notification  to my team when multiple selected jobs are run successfully.

Comment: if you want to send both failure and success you can do like https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/52630/any-way-to-send-notifications-to-different-emails-on-success-failure-of-sqlserve